# SQLite3 update table adding and subtracting values in a consistent way in the same query

Tags: sqlite, sum

As an example I have this table:

```
table accounts:
type  | value
a       100
a       200
a       300
b       100
```

and I need to increment by 1% all accounts of type 'a', and then subtract from the account of type b so the total sum(value) does not change:

```
type  | value
a       101
a       202
a       303
b       94
```

Is any way I can do this in one single update?

Comment: If there are multiple rows for type = 'b' then what is the logic of subtracting from each of them?

Comment: there is just one row for type 'b'

Answer (score 0):

The order of the rows that will be updated is not predetermined, so you need 2 update statements: the 1st will update the row with type = 'b' and the 2nd the rows with type = 'a':

```
update accounts
set value = value - (select sum(0.01 * value) from accounts where type = 'a')
where type = 'b';

update accounts
set value = 1.01 * value
where type = 'a';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9YCjQseDKFf7cdXK7deXsn/1).
Results:

```
| type | value |
| ---- | ----- |
| a    | 101   |
| a    | 202   |
| a    | 303   |
| b    | 94    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression and a subquery that gets the sum.

```
UPDATE accounts
       SET value = CASE
                     WHEN type = 'a' THEN
                       value * 1.01
                     WHEN type = 'b' THEN
                       value - (SELECT sum(value / 1.01 * .01)
                                       FROM accounts
                                       WHERE type = 'a')
                     ELSE
                       value
                   END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5d3a2ceef36870e72b39007b5aec601a)